# Asp.Net Core: HttpRequestException on call to external API

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, tls1.2, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a problem making HTTP calls to an external API using HTTPS (TLS 1.2) from my .NET Core 1.1 web application. The application runs fine locally, but when deployed to Azure app services I get the following exception:

```
exceptionMessage:An error occurred while sending the request.
exceptionType:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
```

The inner exception is:

```
innerExceptionMessage:A security error occurred
innerExceptionType:System.Net.Http.WinHttpException
```

The strange thing is that I don't get this exception on all requests to the external API, it only happens some times.

I noticed that similar issues have been discussed in other SO posts, but *most* of them have been about self-signed certificates. In my case, the remote server is using a certificate signed by GeoTrust.

All calls are being made with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

Related:

- [Asp.Net Core: Calling another REST-Api throws WebException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177825/asp-net-core-calling-another-rest-api-throws-webexception)
- [.net core API Post exception gives NativeErrorCode 12175](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265186/net-core-api-post-exception-gives-nativeerrorcode-12175)
- [HTTPS request fails using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746190/https-request-fails-using-httpclient)
- [Security Error, post with Client Certificate (Self-signed Root) on Azure (Asp.net core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844088/security-error-post-with-client-certificate-self-signed-root-on-azure-asp-ne)

Full stack trace:

```
{ exceptionType: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException", innerException: { innerStacktrace: " at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()", innerExceptionMessage: "A security error occurred", innerExceptionType: "System.Net.Http.WinHttpException" }, stacktrace: " at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Integration.Services.ApiService.<PostResourceToApiAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\integration\src\Integration\Services\ApiService.cs:line 112 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Integration.Services.AccountService.<NotifyOwnerAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\projects\integration\src\Integration\Services\AccountService.cs:line 115 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Integration.Services.AccountService.<CreateAccountAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\projects\integration\src\Integration\Services\AccountService.cs:line 66 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Integration.Services.PartnerService.<CreateAccountAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\projects\integration\src\Integration\Services\PartnerService.cs:line 100 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Integration.Controllers.AccountsController.<Create>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\projects\integration\src\Integration\Controllers\AccountsController.cs:line 92 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()", exceptionMessage: "An error occurred while sending the request." }
```

Comment: could you also get the stack trace as well ?  Also if possible,try to take a [system.net tracing ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing)

Comment: I've added the full stack trace but I haven't got the system.net tracing to work yet.

Comment: Please follow this to enable system.net tracing https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/01/05/enable-system-net-tracing-on-azure-app-service-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server/

Comment: I followed that guide but there is no file written to the directory specified in the `initializeData` property. Maybe the approach described in the article isn't applicable for .NET Core applications.

Comment: That may be right,i have not tried on .net core application.I will check it and update this thread

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue that I've seen is due to this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7812

That explains why I only saw this when the application was deployed to a web appp in Azure, since that is running Windows Server 2012. The real fix for this would be to upgrade to Windows Server 2016 but that is currently not supported for web apps in Azure :-(

My workaround for now is just a simple re-try mechanism which seem to work fairly well.